# Can't import Tabler package in React app (Error: Package path . is not exported from package)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, node-modules

I am importing some Tabler icons in a React component:

**FeatureCards.tsx**

```
import { IconGauge, IconUser, IconCookie } from '@tabler/icons';
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/FeatureCards.tsx 6:0-64

Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package /xx/App/node_modules/@tabler/icons (see exports field in /xx/App/node_modules/@tabler/icons/package.json)
```

In /xx/App/node_modules/@tabler/icons/**package.json**, the export looks like:

```
  "exports": {
    "./*": [
      "./icons/*"
    ]
  },
```

I have tried changing it to..:

```
 "exports": {
    "./*": [
      "./icons/*"
    ],
    ".": "./icons"
  },
```

..per a suggestion online however this gives the new error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@tabler/icons' in '/xx/App/src/components'
```

I've also tried deleting and re-installing my node modules with no luck. I will downgrade for now assuming it's a version problem.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: downgrading tabler to 1.115.0 has rectified the issue for now.

```
npm  i @tabler/icons@1.115.0
```

Comment: have you install the package @tabler/icons

Comment: Yes I have.   "version": "2.4.0",

Comment: i'm also having the same issue

Comment: I would reccomend downgrading to 1.115 which seems stable and contains all of the icons I have used so far. The changelog is found here: https://preview.tabler.io/changelog.html

Answer (score 6):

you should use `@tabler/icons-react` package